# How to close a specific folder with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple program that closes a specific folder every time it gets opened to deny access to said folder. I've tried using `VBScript` , and the codes I was given worked at first, but they failed after some circumstances (like trying to open the specific folder a lot of times in quick succession, or sometimes even after closing an unrelated folder).

The folder I'm trying to close is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

Comment: Where is the code you're having trouble with? N.B. I'd probably use AutoHotKey/AutoIt for manipulating Windows GUI. Is there some reason you can't use Group Policy or permissions to address this?

Comment: I feel like this might be more suited to Powershell than Python, but I'll be interested to see if there's a workable solution.

Comment: @kindall I'm fairly new to Python and I don't have a working code. I've tried using VBScript (because I know a little bit more about VBScript), but since I couldn't get any code to work consistently I thought I could get a simple code that worked, mainly cause I don't know the technical terms necessary to search that code myself. And to answer the second question, I don't want to modify those because I want the effect to last until the program is terminated

Comment: This is never going to be even the slightest bit secure.

Comment: @user2357112 I know that a code like this could easily be terminated, but I want it for less serious purposes, that don't require as much security (to clarify, I simply want to deny access to a folder to a person that probably doesn't even know how to open Task Manager)